# an infinite loop inside a javascript game

Tags: javascript, jquery

my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Qfe6L/2/

```
 $(window).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 32) {
                CreateChuriken();
                $(".Shuriken").animate({ left: '+=300px' }, 'slow');
            }
        });
```

as you can see if you hit on start button and keep on pressing space in a fast way the counter act weird and the amount of enemies created start to be massive the game enter an infinite loop somewhere but i can't find where can anyone help me please

Comment: sorry can't replicate. can you be more exact on how to reproduce the bug?

Comment: It seems to work fine. I'm using Chrome. Which browser (+version) are you using?

Comment: please try hitting on space button when moving the player up and down and see what is happening

Comment: ok, how do you move it up and down? arrows not working for me? :)

Comment: what do u mean arrow is not working they should definitely work you can move it using the up arrow and the down arrow key

Comment: Down arrow doesn't work, Windows, Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: arrows do not work. Shuriken works perfectly and in a fast way.

Comment: on chrome does not work try it using firefox

Comment: Arrows and Shuriken working on Firefox 20

Comment: yes but have u see the infinite loop and the weird behavior ?

Comment: Nope. :(        ........

Comment: How can you have an infinite loop when it's not even looping?

Comment: Chrome 26.0.1410.64 for me - shurikens seem to work fine, no infinite loop, can't move up or down, closest thing to weird behavior is that the enemies at the lowest tier are only half on the screen

Comment: New update - I kept at it for a while, and started to see some slowdown and higher consumption of resources.  I think what you're seeing isn't so much an infinite loop as a memory leak.  Try to make sure that your enemies and shurikens (particularly the shurikens) are garbage collected properly once they're off-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the start button is clicked, you are creating a new timeout, which sets up a 60 second window of spawning enemies and increments the counter. As it has been stated, when you press space to attack, that can also press the start button if the button has focus.

Disable the button when you start things:

```
    $("#Start").click(function () {
        $('#Start').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        startTimer();
        ReleaseEnemies()
    });
```

This will avoid what effectively is running multiple 'copies' of your game logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you press space while a button has focus, the browser counts it as a click.
In my experience multiple hits to the start button cause the problem you described.
Try to eliminate further clicks after the initial (`disable` it, maybe).

Comment: Good catch.  I can verify that multi-clicking the start button makes things act funny (in particular, generating a lot more enemies